# Check a string for multiple regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to run two different regex patterns on a string to compare if the string is a myspace.com or a last.fm url using C#.

I got it working using a single regex with the following code:

```
public string check(string value)
{
    Regex DescRegexShortened = new Regex(@"myspace\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)");
    Match DescRegexShortenedMatch = DescRegexShortened.Match(value);

    string url = "";

    if (DescRegexShortenedMatch.Success)
    {
        url = DescRegexShortenedMatch.Value;
    }

    return url;
}
```

Now my question, is there a simplier way to check if the string is either a myspace.com or a last.fm url?

```
Regex DescRegexShortened = new Regex(@"myspace\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)");
Regex mySpaceRegex = new Regex(@"last\.fm\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)");
```

for example something like:

if string matches regex1 or regex2 then ...

Comment: It looks like you only care about the last.fm or myspace.com and not what comes after that. Could you not just do a string.StartsWith or string.Contains instead of the regex pattern? Or is usually regex required in your case?

Comment: Your regex fails on `myspace.com?a=b`. Michael is correct.

Comment: I'm currently uploading a text document containing usernames to the application. Now the application would use a API to receive the twitter users bio and website. Now every site will be added to a C# list and will be run through those two regex patterns which check if the url is either a myspace or last.fm url So the username behind it doesn't matter

Comment: The way you describe it, you may just as well use `if (value.Contains("myspace.com/") || value.Contains("last.fm/"))`

Comment: Oh god. Thank you! I didnt think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is too obvious:

```
var rx1 = new Regex(@"myspace\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)");
var rx2 = new Regex(@"last\.fm\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)");

if ( rx1.IsMatch(value) || rx2.IsMatch(value) )
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternation in a regular expression to check for different values instead of checking multiple regular expressions:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<domain>myspace\.com|last\.fm)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*");
var match = regex.Match(value);
if (match.Success)
{
    var domain = match.Groups["domain"].Value;
    // ...
}
else
{
    // No match
}
```

In this case the alternation is `myspace\.com|last\.fm` which matches either `myspace.com` or `last.fm`. The alternation is inside a named group `domain` and if the regular expressions matches you can access the value of the this named group as I do in the code.

Instead of using regular expressions you might just check if the string starts with either `myspace.com` or `last.fm` or if the URL's are real URL's using proper syntax like `http://myspace.com/bla` you can create and instance of the `Uri` class and then check the `Host` property.

If you want to use regular expressions you should probably change it to not match domains like `fakemyspace.com` but still match `MYSPACE.COM`.

Comment: A word boundary at the beginning would be a better excuse to use a regex here.